# Git checkout latest commit for remote ref

Tags: git, github

I need to write a custom deployment tool for git where I can deploy either **from a tag** or the **latest commit of a branch**.

So in this case, I need a generic solution.

How do I checkout the latest commit from a remote in Git by having a ref?

e.g. I have the following refs

```
refs/tags/1.0.0
refs/heads/master
```

So I do this:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout <ref>
```

This works for tags, but not for branches.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "remote commit", especially since your example is using a local (not a remote-tracking) branch.  However, `git checkout origin/master` (for instance) should work fine.  The only special treatment `checkout` has for local branches is that, by default, it gets "on" them rather than "detaching" HEAD to a specific commit.  That means a new commit will update that branch.  To force a detach with a local branch, use `--detach`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to put this in a script that takes a ref and gets me into the latest "state" that the remote repository has with this ref (in my case a tag or a branch).
Do I need to differentiate between tag and branch in order to achieve this? ```git checkout origin/master```only works for branches, right?

Comment: Well, `fetch --all` simply fetches all remotes; their branches normally wind up in `refs/remotes/<remote>/<branch>`; and you can spell that out entirely, or use the abbreviated form `<remote>/<branch>`, as noted in the gitrevisions documentation.  This does assume you have set up all these remotes in the usual way.

Comment: Try `<remote>/master` where `<remote>` is the name of the git remote you're getting fetch from.